# Cannot delete files from a directory

Tags: c#, winforms, file, copy, delete-file

I am describing my work process bellow:

1. I get image files from a directory.
2. Creating a `PictureBox` array for displaying the images.
3. Creating a `Image` array from the files that I got from the directory. I am creating this array for making the image source of `PictureBox`.
4. I am copying the files to another directory. By this:

   ```
   File.Copy(allFiles[i],fullPath+fullName+"-AA"+nameString+ext);
   ```
5. Now I want to delete the files from the directory. For this I am doing this:

   ```
   File.Delete(allFiles[i]);
   ```

But its giving me this error:

> The process cannot access the file 'C:\G\a.jpg' because it is being used by another process.

Please tell me how to resolve this? I didn't attach the full code here because it'll be large. Please ask me if you want to see any part of my code.

Comment: You must make a copy first and use the copy, not the original.

Comment: How are you loading the images? For example, are you using `Image.FromFile(allFiles[i])` or something else?

Comment: @SFLee > Yes I am doing this `Image.FromFile(allFiles[i])`

Comment: That's the problem... Hold on, I'll write up the answer.

Comment: There, I've written an answer for it. Please check it out. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chances are you are loading the image directly from the file. For example,

```
PictureBox[i] = Image.FromFile(allFiles[i]);
```

If you look up the documentation for the `Image.FromFile` method, you will find that it actually locks the file until the `Image` is disposed. (In fact, most other loading methods in the `Image` class also locks the file until the `Image` is disposed.)

So to work around this problem, copy the picture file contents to memory and load it from there. For example,

```
PictureBox[i] = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(allFiles[i])));
```

That way, the file itself will remain unlocked and you can freely move/delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it's being used.

Copy the files to another directory first (Step 4),

Delete the old directory

then do the third step (assigning it to a array and loading it to PictureBox) from the newly copied directory.

Alternative:

You must close the stream handler before deleting the files..

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
 using (PictureBox[i] = Image.FromStream(fs))
 {
  ...
 }
```

Comment: I can't do this. At first I've to display the images and then on button click I need to move them to a directory.

Comment: Then you have to unload the images from your picture box before deleting it. You have to clear the imagebox between step 4 and step 5.