# Copy list of photos to another folder

Tags: c#, image, copy, nullreferenceexception

I have an listbox with a list of photos (in listbox items i have the directory of photos) how can i copy these photos to an chosen directory?

```
int numberoflistbox = listBox2.Items.Count;
string[] number = new string[numberoflistbox];
for (i = 0; i <= listBox2.Items.Count; i++)
{
    number[i] = listBox2.Items[i].ToString();
    foreach (string f in number)
    {
        string a = toolStripTextBox2.Text;
        string b = toolStripTextBox1.Text;
        string fName = f.Substring(a.Length + 1);

        File.Copy(Path.Combine(a, fName), Path.Combine(a, fName), true);
    }
}
```

I'm trying this code but it ain't working.

Sorry guys I've made a mistake in the backup directory, but still ain't working:

```
 File.Copy(Path.Combine(a, fName), Path.Combine(b, fName), true);
```

error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

for this line :  `string fName = f.Substring(a.Length + 1);`

Comment: By "aint working", it's failing or doing nothing?  Error message?

Comment: Please explain the problem you're having. Are you getting an exception/error? Is the code running but just not copying the photos?

Comment: it shows me this error :
The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\Ja\Desktop\10287328_301885279970384_684647408_n.jpg' because it is being used by another process.

Comment: If you don't obviously have any of the photos open in another application, what happens if you log out and back in to Windows?

Comment: Close the program you are viewing the photo with!!

Comment: I am viewing the photos momentally with my c# application, and while its runing i want them to copy in another folder.

Comment: What is the code you are using to view the photos in your C# application?

Comment: Chances are you are having a similar problem to [Can not delete files from a directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23465794/can-not-delete-files-from-a-directory/23466030). Please try out the answer from there.

Comment: Now im facing with another problem, i used this method to copy the photos but i changed it a bit for listbox items:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6cfw35a(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Another bug: Shouldn't your `foreach` loop be _outside_ your `for` loop?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @SFLee hmm not sure, cuz when its outside the for loop it shows me this error :InvalidArgument=Value of '2' is not valid for 'index'.
in this row: `number[i] = listBox2.Items[i].ToString();`

Comment: Where do you move the `foreach` loop to? Above the `for` loop or below? It should be below.

Answer (score 0):

Use FileStream to assign a picture to a control programmatically So that the main image remains unopened.

```
var fs = new FileStream("Image Address",FileMode.Open);
Image img = Image.FromStream(fs);
picturebox.Image=img;
fs.Close();
fs.Dispose();
```